# Show only Dynamically Added selected Element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When I am trying to show selected element value on click, it was showing all element values.. in below code if i added usernames, when we click on any label it will have to show their corresponding delete icon.. but here it was showing delete icon to all added labels. Can u please tell me how to solve this??

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fXVlLYmWTRsmhSRYPg91?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);
var counter = 0
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.add = function(index) {
        var username = '<div ng-click="showRemove()"><label>User Name</label>//click//<input type="text"><button id="buttonId'+counter+'" ng-show="remove">-</button></div>';
        var user = $compile(username)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(user);
            };
            $scope.showRemove = function(){
              $scope.remove = true;
            }
++counter;
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add($index)">Add</button>
<hr>
 <div id="add"></div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you need more explanation of delegated event handlers, just ask. I will copy some from another of my answers (done this one a lot of times) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay close to the way you tried to solve it, this could be a solution:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);
var counter = 0
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.add = function(index) {
       var username = '<div ng-click="showRemove('+counter+')"><label>User Name</label>//click//<input type="text"><button id="buttonId'+counter+'" ng-show="'+counter+ ' == active">-</button></div>';
       var user = $compile(username)($scope);
       angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(user);
       ++counter;
   };
   $scope.showRemove = function(counter){
       $scope.active = counter;
   }

   $scope.active = -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a delegated jQuery event handler and not inline event handlers for dynamically added elements. The jQuery way is better if you use jQuery anyway.

Add a class to the remove buttons instead e.g. `class="deleteme"`:

```
var username = '<div ng-click="showRemove()"><label>User Name</label>//click//<input type="text"><button id="buttonId'+counter+'" ng-show="remove" class="deleteme">-</button></div>';
```

Then the handler becomes

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteme', function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

`document` is just a common ancestor to the dynamic elements. It can be any common ancestor above your user entries.

### Notes:

- Delegated event handlers work by listening for the event (click) to bubble up to a common ancestor. `document` is the best default if nothing else is closer/convenient. They then apply the jQuery selector, at event time, to the elements in the bubble-chain. It then applies your function, to only the matching elements that caused the event. The `this` value passed to the event function will be the matched item that was clicked.
- inline handlers (like `onclick=""`) separate your event registration from the event handler for no benefit.
- You should try chose the closest common ancestor, to the elements, as the target of the delegated event. Even though `document` is one level higher, it is a better default than `body` as `body` can fail in certain circumstances.
- Delegated events are faster to connect than individual event handlers. The trade-off is a slight reduction in speed at event time, but (and it's a big but), the speed difference at event time will never be noticed because you cannot click a mouse 50,0000 times per second :)

Comment: thank you .. i have known how to use Delegated event handler works using jquery,, u given me nice subject.. tnx alot :)

Comment: @VijjuSena: unfortunately I don't use Angular so I see there are other ways to solve it too :)